# $.get problem with xml data

Tags: jquery, xml, get

I'm sure I'm missing something completely obvious, but perhaps someone can point it out. I want to pull information from a .php file as follows:

```
$("body").click(function(){
$.get('ajax/xml-content.php',
    function(data) {
    $('#main-content').css('border','2px solid red');
        },"html");
});
```

Here is the xml-content.php source code:

```
<data> 
<image>images/thumbs/test-9-thumb.jpg</image> 
<image>images/thumbs/test-2-thumb.jpg</image>
<image>images/thumbs/test-3-thumb.jpg</image>  
</data>
```

If I switch the data type in the above jquery to "xml" (which is what I want to do), then the callback function doesn't fire. If it's not included or left as "html", it will fire.  Obviously there's something incorrect about xml-content.php...what is the obvious thing I'm missing? Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the content type as XML?

```
<?php  
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
?>
```